# White space bottom Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, footer

I have a misterous gap between footer and the end of the window. It's only on Firefox.

http://agendakinder.wampanas.com

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really explain why, but from what I can see, this is caused due to the usage of positioning.

But where you have .logo-footer for the image of the giraffe, disable position:relative; and use margin-top:-232px;

Comment: No worries and great to hear :) would you mind marking my answer as it was helpful?